# confusion about float and clear

Tags: css, css-float

I have a simple example:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Float</title>
        <style>
            .name2:after {
                content: "";
                clear: both;
                display: table;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div style="float: left; background-color: red">
                name 1
            </div>
            <div class="name2" style="float: left; background-color: blue">
                name 2
            </div>
            <div style="background-color: purple">
                name 3
            </div>
            <div style="background-color: pink">
                name 4
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            next line
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and the result is the following
[image]
I expected that the div with content "name 3" is below the two floating divs "name 1" and "name 2". Why doesn't the clear: both in the style section have any effect?
I know that I can write instead

```
.name2 + div {
    clear: both;
}
```

and I get the desired behavior.
[image]

Comment: In the 2023 don't use float for layout.

Comment: `.name2:after` will render as if an actual element had been inserted into `.name` as that one's last child node. So that is something very different, than applying clear to the next div element that is _outside_ of `.name2`.

Comment: I changed it to Flexbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot clear float by using the clear property on an element that is **inside** the float element. The clear should be done after and not inside.

The technique of the pseudo element is generally used on the container that contain all the float elements to clear them since the `::after` is placed **after** them